# Android adb and C++

Tags: android, c++, mfc, adb, file-transfer

I am writing a C++ program (MFC) that is to automatically transfer file between a desktop and a tablet.  However, the tablet I am using is recognized as an MTP device and is not assigned a drive letter; therefore I'm unable to access the internal folder from C++ (unless there is a way, but I couldn't find one).

Is there a way to run adb through C++ to automate the file transfer.  Or maybe through a VB Script?

I'm just trying to find anyway to transfer the files automatically.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb push` is an obvious way, running adb from `system()` or `::CreateProcess()`.

Comment: sorry, can you give me some more direction...I'm not very good with C++ and don't know how to apply your suggestion

Comment: `system("<path-to-adb> push <some-file>");` this way it invokes adb to push a file to the device.

Comment: much appreciated, that worked, I used system("cd "path to adb" & adb push local remote")

Answer (score 0):

You fail to get the MTP assignment when you have debugging enabled by default. You can manually navigate the menu in the device and select to connect mass storage, (at which time you should see the stroage appear with it's respective drive letter), or disable debugging and choose to connect mass storage as the default when usb is connected, (and it will always connect and show the drive letter). Once the device is in the correct mode you should have no trouble connecting to the onboard storage.

Comment: unfortunately this tablet doesn't have that option, it only connects through MTP as a "portable device"

Comment: @vikki I didn't state that turning off debugging will auto mount the card. I stated you must select that option in the menu. However, with my devices, if auto-debugging is on, storage will not auto-connect even if the option is selected. You must manually select the option to connect storage, or disable debugging to auto-connect as storage.

Comment: this tablet is odd, it does not have the option of being connected as a mass storage drive